# Deploy time error (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider ) in Jboss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jboss, jboss7.x

Our project is in Jetty server and work completely then this project is deployed in Jboss 7 server, but there are some errors.

I make war file and copy and past in E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments folder and auto-deploy become start and give this error :

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
```

**i try to add path in edit jboss_home/modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml and add path com/sun/net/ssl/internal , but error is not remove**

So how to remove this error?

Detail Error :

```
13:33:03,769 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factor
y.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocati
on of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [org.spri
ngframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.spring
framework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:
3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.
beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.
0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [org.springfr
amework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900) [org.springf
ramework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455) [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M
1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1
]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:336) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:752) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:72) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0
.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152) [org.springframework.b
eans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [or
g.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider from [Module "deployment.mwp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 43 more

13:33:03,856 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mwp]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialize
d event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'log4jInitialization' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nest
ed exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [org.spri
ngframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.spring
framework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:
3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.
beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.
0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [org.springfr
amework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900) [org.springf
ramework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455) [org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M
1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1
]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:215) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.
1.0.M1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:336) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:752) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415) [log4j-1.2.16.jar:]
        at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:72) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273) [org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.doInvoke(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:162) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.0
.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:152) [org.springframework.b
eans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [or
g.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [org.s
pringframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar:3.1.0.M1]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider from [Module "deployment.mwp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 43 more

13:33:04,076 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
13:33:04,078 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/mwp] startup failed due to previous errors
13:33:04,094 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mwp]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Closing Spring root WebApplicationCo
ntext
13:33:04,107 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mwp: org.jbos
s.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./mwp: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jboss 7 looks for dependencies in the modules folder. You can't just go in the modules.xml file and add new modules if they don't actually exist.

What you need to do is find out whether there is a jar containing the missing class, if it exist then you need to add a reference to that module from your project, if does not exist, you need to manually download it and copy it to the modules directory and then reference it.

You have several ways you can reference it:

1. Add a classpath entry to your manifest file: `Classpath: com.sun.net`
2. Add a global reference to that module in your standalone.xml by adding a [Global module](https://community.jboss.org/message/731450).

For more details, look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home).

Comment: see our manifest file :,, Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_01 (Oracle Corporation)
Classpath: com.sun.net and get same error so get other idea for remove this error .....

Comment: Is there a jar under modules/com/sun/net/main that contains the missing class?

Comment: modules/com/sun/net/main path is completed in our system then what will do ? our system have modules/com/sun and end it. so am i make it OR other way for put this jar ? - Thanks , kamlesh

Comment: Did you read my answer? You need to look for the jar containing the missing class (com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider) and put it under modules/com/sun/net/main. please look at the link in the bottom of the answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks give me ans.  No ,there is not a jar under modules/com/sun/net/main. so what will do ? and how to get this gar file ?

Comment: Look for a jsse.jar in your system, or You can try this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html#jsse-1.0.3_04-fcs-do-oth-JPR

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13297/discussion-between-kamlesh0606-and-ftom2)

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this problem in jboss 7.1.1Final . I was getting it for X509TrustManager.java from com.sun.net.ssl package  from rt.jar inside jdk 7.

I solved it by adding

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="sun.jdk">
<resources>
    <!-- currently jboss modules has not way of importing services from
    classes.jar so we duplicate them here -->
    <resource-root path="service-loader-resources"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <system export="true">
        <paths>
            ...
      <path name="com/sun/net/ssl"/>
           ...
        </paths>
        <exports>
            <include-set>
                <path name="META-INF/services"/>
            </include-set>
        </exports>
    </system>
</dependencies>
```

in module.xml under modules/sun of jboss 7.

Hope this will help anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem what I see is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider`

you need to add dependencies in your web app's manifest file, My suggestion is, read that section from the manual first

```
To import it using jboss-deployment-structure.xml:
```

```
<dependencies>

  <module name="system" >

     <imports>

        <include-set>

           <path name="com/sun/ssl/internal/ssl"/>

         </include-set>

      </imports>

    </module>

</dependencies>
```

Please refer below link.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Comment: I tried but get ERROR like : 14:07:15,899 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mwp.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mwp.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "mwp.war"

Comment: Dependency on what? It's a standard JDK class.

Answer (score 0):

That class has been provided with all Oracle/Sun JDks since 1.4, i.e. 8-9 years.

Either:

1. You are using a non-Sun/Oracle JDK
2. You are using the classname com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider in your code or configuration file(s), or
3. You have something seriously wrong with your Java installation

Comment: this project in spring project and this completely run in jetty server and then this run in jboss as 7 server then get this error . so help , how to remove error in jboss 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Open module definition for **sun.jdk** module. For latest EAP, path is : JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\sun\jdk\main\module.xml

Add following to paths section :

```
<path name="com/sun/ssl/internal/ssl"/>
<path name="com/sun/net/ssl"/>
```

2.Add following to jboss-deployment-structure.xml inside your WEB-INF folder

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="sun.jdk"/>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to file => WEB_INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl"/>
                   </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
     </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```